# Do final variables need to be given a value immediately after declaring them

Tags: java, variables, instantiation, final

Is it possible to assign a value to a final variable anywhere else in the program? Or is it mandatory that they be assigned a value upon creation?

```
class TestClass() {
//this won't compile but is it possible to assign str a value anywhere else in the program?
public static final String str;
}
```

Comment: If you don't init the value at the definition line, where would you possibly assign it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign a value when it's declared - in the constructor if it's not static, in the static initializer block if it is.  Once you set the value, it can't be modified.

Do it like this:

```
public class FinalTest {
    private static final String CONSTANT;

    private final String value;

    static {
        CONSTANT = "Hello";
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        FinalTest ft = ((args.length > 0) ? new FinalTest(args[0]) : new FinalTest(CONSTANT));
        System.out.println(ft);
    }

    public FinalTest(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() { return this.value; }
}
```

Comment: can you give an example of how else you can initialize it? i.e. you mention in the constructor...when i do that it still doesn't compile though.

Comment: Slight correction: final fields aren't initialized to null. Otherwise you'd never be able to put another value in them. A final field must be explicitly initialized exactly once. Anything else is a compilation failure.

Comment: The code that I wrote compiles and runs.  I agree - they have to be initialized.  I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Local variables

A `final` **variable** needs to be assigned a value exactly once **before it is accessed.** This means that if it's never assigned a value and never accessed, the compiler won't complain.

```
void foo() {
    final int a; // Never assigned, but never accessed either, so no problem
    final int b = 7;

    System.out.println("b is " + b);

    // System.out.println("a is " + a);
    // Uncommenting the above line would cause a compile error
}
```

## Static fields

A similar logic applies to `final` **static fields**, except it's assumed that they will be accessed at some point, so they must be initialized either on the definition line or in a static initializer block.

Here's what [the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) has to say about static initialization blocks:

> This works well when the initialization value is available and the initialization can be put on one line. However, this form of initialization has limitations because of its simplicity. If initialization requires some logic (for example, error handling or a for loop to fill a complex array), simple assignment is inadequate. Instance variables can be initialized in constructors, where error handling or other logic can be used. To provide the same capability for class variables, the Java programming language includes static initialization blocks.
>
> Note: It is not necessary to declare fields at the beginning of the class definition, although this is the most common practice. It is only necessary that they be declared and initialized before they are used.

## Instance fields

While we're at it, a `final` **instance (non-static) field** must be assigned a value exactly once **by the time the instance initialization is complete**. This means there are three places where you can initialize one (but you must pick one):

#### 1. Definition line:

```
// For when you know the answer
class Foo {
    final int theAnswer = 42;
}
```

#### 2. Constructor:

```
// For when you need to have the answer passed in
class Foo {
    final int theAnswer;

    Foo(int answer) {
        theAnswer = answer;
    }
}

// Or for when you need to do some computation
class Bar {
    static final int ANSWER_COUNT = 10;
    final int[] answers;

    Foo() {
        answers = new int[ANSWER_COUNT];
        for (int i = 0; i < ANSWER_COUNT; i++) {
            answers[i] = i;
        }
    }
```

#### 3. Initializer block:

```
// For when you need to do some computation and have many constructors
class Bar {
    static final int ANSWER_COUNT = 10;
    final int[] answers;

    {
        answers = new int[ANSWER_COUNT];
        for (int i = 0; i < ANSWER_COUNT; i++) {
            answers[i] = i;
        }
    }

    // I have many constructors and don't want to copy-paste 
    // the initialization logic above to all of them
    Bar() { ... }
    Bar(int i) { ... }
    Bar(String blah) { ... }
}
```

From [the same page in the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), regarding initializer blocks:

> The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor. Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between multiple constructors.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you posted, the field is `static` so it could be given a value from within a static initialization block:

```
static {
    str = "my string";
}
```

For non-`static` fields, they can either be initialized in the constructor, or in an instance initializer block:

```
class TestClass {
    private final String str;

    {
        str = "my string";
    }

    TestClass() {

    }
}
```

Comment: what if it wasn't static? can you still do the same within a non-static initialization block?

Comment: Edited to demonstrate an instance initialization block. However, I'd recommend only using initialization blocks if necessary as they can be a bit confusing. IMO static final fields should almost always be given a value where they are declared, and final instance fields should be given a value where declared or in the constructor.